# Cassandra : cqlsh noHostAvailable error on select query

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am getting an error 
:noHostAvailable in cqlsh 
when I am running select query for a table, although I am able to insert in that table.

When I tried nodetool status command, I found...

```
 Datacenter: datacenter1


 Status=Up/Down|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
 --  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               

 Rack

 DN  172.22.4.140  ?          256          65.0%             
 UN  127.0.0.1     2.05 MiB   256          69.8%             
 DN  172.22.8.44   ?          256          65.2%
```

I only have a setup for single node cluster, how to change this setting to single node, also do I need to alter my keyspace, which I suspect expecting more than one node.

Comment: What is the replication factor (amount of copies of the information) and consistency level used? Most likely you will need to address first the nodes that are reported as "down" (DN) to be able to insert and select.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes issue:
Have a look at your `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yml` section seeds. 
it should contains only your ip
- seeds: "YOUR_IP"

Select:
You need to check replication factor, therefore run:
    cqlsh> describe keyspace YUOR_KEYSAPCE;

If it is more then 1 
You can change it by:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name 
WITH REPLICATION =  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

and run `nodetool repair`

If you can't find the issue after that, you can rename the cluster:

Log into cqlsh

`UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME' where key='local';`

exit cqlsh

`nodetool flush`

edit cassandra.yaml cluster name to YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME.

Restart cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you data is residing on the node which is currently down.
As per the above output, In 3 node cluster 2 nodes are down and replication factor is 1. In this situation your select query is going to coordinator node but coordinator node is not getting the data from other nodes cause those are down. please try to up other nodes and try SELECT it will work.